# Rank-Nullity Theorem Doubt

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a linear transformation $T : V \to W$ where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces.

It is known that the transformation of any vector in the form $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + ... + a_zv_z$ (where $v_1,v_2, \ldots ,v_z$ are not in the nullspace of $T$ and form a linearly independent set in $V$) yields $a_1T(v_1) + a_2T(v_2) + \cdots + a_zT(v_z)$ ( where $T(v_1), T(v_2), \ldots, T(v_z)$ form a linearly independent set in $W$ ).

So that means that for every linearly independent set $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_z$ in $V$ (with vectors not in the nullspace of $T$) we have another corresponding linearly independent set $T(v_1),T(v_2),\ldots,T(v_z)$ in $W$ .

Considering $v_1,v_2,..,v_z$ a linaernly independent set in $V$ such that $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_z$ are not inside NullSpace of $T$, then :
Why does $c_1 = c_2 = ... = c_z = 0$ in $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + .... + c_zv_z = 0$ imply that $c_1 = c_2 = ... = c_z = 0$ in $c_1T(v_1) + c_2T(v_2) + \cdots + c_zT(v_z) = 0$?

Is it obvious?  I can prove it formally but I'm looking for an intuition as to why that's true.

Comment: You have some confusions here.  Most of all, a general linear transformation does not take a linearly independent set in $V$ to a linearly set in $W$!  This property occurs precisely if the kernel is $0$.  If possible, can you fix this and rephrase your question?  Or is this really what you want to ask about?

Comment: I was talking about the vectors v1,v2,..,vz that i introduced in my second sentence

Comment: Your second sentence “It is known that...” is not true. When the chosen set of linearly independent vectors are not in the null space, it is not necessarily the case that their images are linearly independent. Example: consider a vector $n\ne0$ in the null space, and another vector $v$ not in the null space. Then $\{v,v+n\}$ is a linearly independent set. But the image set is $\{f(v),f(v)\}$

Comment: @nerdy: Okay: if $v_1,\ldots,v_z$ are linearly independent and do not lie in the nullspace of $T$, this *still* does not imply that $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_z)$ are linearly independent.  For example consider $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $(x,y) \mapsto x$, let $v_1 = (1,0)$ and $v_2 = (1,1)$.  Then $T(v_1) - T(v_2) = 0$.

Comment: Despite the problems, this question essentially boils down to "Why is $T(0)=0$?" But this is just what linear transformations do!

Comment: @Matt: if that is true, then the problems are more important than the question itself.

Comment: Actually, I think I misread the question. The phrasing in that second to last paragraph is really awkward.

Comment: I had a misconception that appending any linearnly independent set v1,v2,...,vz outside of the span[B] to the set of basis vectors for B, would yield a linearnly independent set, no matter what vectors we would choose.The problem i see, is that we can make a linearnly combination of v1,v2,..,vz to generate one of the basis vector. Is it true that we can also take a linear combination of v1,v2,...,vz,b1,b2,...,bu-1 to generate a basis vector bu ?

Answer (score 1):

What you state is not true.  Here is a counterexample.

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

The vectors $v_1=(1,0)$ and $v_2=(0,1)$ are linearly independent and are not in the nullspace of $T$, but their sum is, so that their images are not linearly independent.